# Is it necessary to recreate all Data Flow tasks after changing a Data Flow Source connection manager?

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I’m quite new to SSIS and have inherited a number of packages that all do roughly the same thing: import Excel data via an OLE DB connection before importing to SQL Server. The data flows all have twenty odd lookup, merge and multicast tasks that handle validation, transformation and error reporting.

It appears that if any changes are made to data source/connection manager all the data tasks need to be recreated and re-linked in order for the changes to be available and the package to work properly. This is quite a laborious process if all that’s happening is a small change such as an extra field in the data source.

I’m wondering if there is a way of getting round this (maybe re-architecting the packages in a different way) or is it just something you have to live with when working with SSIS? I’m using Visual Studio 2008 with SQL Server 2008 but planning to upgrade to 2012 before long.

Thanks in advance for any advice!

Comment: Have you tried just adding the new field in using the ConnectionMgr/OLEDB Source's Advanced Editor?  It sounds as though you're dealing with the change by creating an entirely new ConnMgr, which (as you've found) upsets all the downstream data tasks.

Comment: Thanks SebTHU I wasn't aware of the Advanced Editor and it does seem to help. I've also moved most validation into a script component which makes it easier (for me) to follow the data flow and create useful error reporting